# What does "day to second" actually do?

Tags: postgresql

The [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-datetime.html) says there's an interval type, with the following syntax:

> ```
> interval [ fields ] [ (p) ]
> ```
>
> The interval type has an additional option, which is to restrict the set of stored fields by writing one of these phrases:
>
> ```
> YEAR
> MONTH
> [Ed: and many more]
> DAY TO SECOND
> [Ed: and many more]
> ```

But what does specifying one of these options actually mean? In particular, I observe that, say, `hour to second` does not actually prevent you from inserting rows that have day, week, month, or year values. Those fields are even stored, contrary to what the documentation says!

```
> create table test ( test interval hour to second );
CREATE TABLE
> insert into test values ( 'P1Y' );
INSERT 0 1
> select * from test;
 test 
------
 P1Y
(1 row)
```

What behavior, if any, is affected by specifying one of the additional options?

I am using version 12.6, if that matters.

Comment: Interesting.  The documentation even talks about this; apparently only the shorter bound is useful.  If you do 'P1MT2H30M'::INTERVAL DAY TO HOUR, the month is stored but the minutes are discarded.

Comment: @TimRoberts Nice, that seems like an answer! Bonus points for linking to the part of the documentation that you found that tidbit in...

Comment: If you want the docs section see here [Interval input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT) 8.5.4. Interval Input in the part that start 'In the alternative format: ...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the upper bound is ignored, but the lower bound does actually restrict things. The documentation also [says this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT), a bit later (its import had escaped me on my first reading!):

> Also, field values “to the right” of the least significant field allowed by the fields specification are silently discarded. For example, writing `INTERVAL '1 day 2:03:04' HOUR TO MINUTE` results in dropping the seconds field, but not the day field.